# get directory of active perl file

Tags: perl, directory

I working with perl and have a file saved in directory like so:

```
/root/dir_1/dir_2/dir_3/dir_4/perl_file.pl
```

What I am trying to do from within the perl file itself is to get the string of `/root ... dir_4/` or just `dir_4/` so I can then use that to make another directory (there's a specific pattern I can use to make the new directory).

I have been looking at File::Copy and File::Basename which seem to require you to specify the path, but I want my path to be variable based on the file that is run. It seems very simple and probably something I am just overlooking, but is this possible?

In pseudo-code, I am looking for something like `my $dir = UpOneDirectory(thisperlfile) or FilePath(thisperlfile)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
say $RealBin;
```

Comment: I hate the way FinBin _works_. I don't like exported variable. I'd if it used  function.

Comment: @David W., It's not exported by default. You can always use `$FindBin::RealBin` instead. You could also submit a patch that adds `sub RealBin { $RealBin }`

Comment: It's actually what I do. I don't export the variables.

Comment: @David W., But you're ok with importing functions?

Comment: @ikegami When you see a variable, your inclination is to look at your program to see where you're setting it. When you see an unknown function, you inclination is to see where it's imported.

Answer (score 1):

```
use File::Basename;
use Cwd qw( abs_path );

my $dir = dirname(abs_path($0));
```

Answer (score 0):

...or... if you don't want to depend on an external module, you can do this with a one-line regex substitution:

```
(my $me = $0) =~ s#(^/.*?)/?[^/]*$#\1#;
```

This will assign a string value to `$me` that represents the path to the directory containing the current script.

Here's how it works.  $0 contains the path to the currently executing script.  We want to assign it to `$me` but we also want to manipulate it with a regex substitution, so we put the assignment inside parenthesis (note, the "my" declaration must go inside the parens as well (or perl will barf)).

The regex matches the initial '/' followed by all characters up to the final '/' and then all non '/' characters to the end of the string (note: the regex is anchored on both ends using '^' and '$').  A grouping set is then used to substitute everything up to (but not including) the final '/' as the new string value.  IOW: the directory component of the path.

Also note that all this extra fluff is simply to deal with the case where a file resides in the root directory and we want the result to actually be '/' (instead of '').  If we didn't need to cover this case, the regex could be much simpler, like so:

```
(my $me = $0) =~ s#/[^/]*$##; # DON'T USE THIS ONE  (Use the above example instead)
```

...but that doesn't cover all the bases.